# Any way to reveal .paw file in Paw 3?

Tags: paw-app

Paw 2 had a popup menu with options like "move to" and "show in Finder"; Paw 3 just has a non-draggable icon and no menu.  Ideally there'd be a proxy icon like most Mac apps, but I'd take a "show in Finder"… is that gone or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The Show in Finder option was added in the latest release (3.0.6), you can fin it in File>Show in Finder

Comment: Thanks for adding it! Probably better as an answer…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From version 3.0.6 you can do it from `File > Show in Finder`.